# C# Anti Aliased lines over a transparent winform

Tags: c#, winforms, antialiasing

I'm working on a project that essentially draws an overlay onto the screen with some quick use buttons, however to achieve this I need to draw polygons onto a winform which is completely invisible.

Doing such a thing is fairly easy using a transparency key HOWEVER issues occur happen when I try and make the jagged polygons smooth using Anti Aliasing. This is because it merges the colour of the lines with the colour of the transparency key, making it fairly ugly:

[image: Anti Aliased polygon on a transparent form]

The code I'm using to draw an anti aliased polygon, fairly simple, nothing special.

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

e.Graphics.DrawPolygon( 
    new Pen( 
    new SolidBrush( 
        Color.Black )
        , 1 )
        , pointCharm );
```

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your Q correctly, but instead of using a transparency key, would it be an option to use Color.FromArgb for your polygons and specify the alpha-channel parameter (0 is transparent, 255 is opaque)?

Comment: The problem is that anti-aliased pixels are semi-transparent therefore the TP-key will shine through. There is no alpha channel for the From's Backcolor. I doubt it can be solved; maybe drawing the lines twice with a pen size of 1.5 and a darkgray color and the normal black 1f pen width on top will look good enough. If the screen/ form won't move/change a lot maybe a workaraound by drawing on a scrennshot and drawing the result onto a region from a grphicspath from the polygons could also work, but that'll not be very responsive..

Comment: The TransparencyKey color being visible is only part of the problem.  The much bigger one is that anti-aliasing can only work against a well-defined background color.  So the AA pixels can blend the foreground into the background.  Trouble is, your background color is entirely unpredictable.  It is whatever color(s) the windows behind yours happen to have.  The only possible trick you could consider is creating a screenshot first.  Draw that bitmap, then the lines on top of it.  Okayish for something like a splash screen, it stops looking like transparency after a while of course.

Comment: So, are we making a [Tempest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(video_game)) game?  :-)

Comment: Tempest used a vector display, not a raster display like we have nowadays.  Perfect analog lines.  Flickering like a cheap motel when the going got semi-tough however :)